# How do I select between mobile navbar and desktop navbar when navbar of unknown width?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue application that has menu items across the top in a nav bar fashion. The number of menu items changes based on the type of user logged in. Sometimes it might be 3 items, some times it could be up to 6 items. 
I am trying to figure out how to determine when to switch between the desktop version of this navbar where the items are layed out as a row of buttons and the mobile version where the menus are hidden under in a slide in type drawer.

I have overriden the updated() life cycle hook to select the appropriate view on startup. I am using ref on a div that contains the menu buttons. From that I can get scrollWidth (the amount of pixels needed to display all the buttons) and clientWidth (the amount of pixels the div has been given). I have overflow: hidden.

From that I can determine when I need to switch from the desktop to the mobile view. I am using a resizeObserver to catch resize. This is working great to switch from desktop to mobile.

But the problem is that once I am in mobile, the desktop navbar isn't part of the dom so i don't know how many pixels are needed to render it so I don't know when to switch back from mobile to desktop as the user resizes the window bigger.

I also don't know how wide the menu buttons will be for different languages.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem is that once I am in mobile, the desktop navbar isn't part of the dom so i don't know how many pixels are needed to render it so I don't know when to switch back from mobile to desktop as the user resizes the window bigger.

So just hide them with `visibility`:

```html
<div class='wrapper' :class='[mode]'>
  <div class='items' ref='items'>
    <div class='item' v-for='item in items'>Item {{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;

  &.desktop {
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
}

.items {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzo3yw1a/)

**Edit to add more information**:

This answer caused me to rethink my approach to the question. I was looking at switching between two different navbar contents. But that isn't compatible with what is being suggested as an answer. The key to the answer is that both the mobile and the desktop navbar elements are going to be present at the same time. The difference is that the desktop elements are going to be squeezed into a smaller and smaller space and then made invisible using the visibility property.

Note about the visibility property: It leaves the element in the DOM and on the screen. The screen still renders the page as if the element was visibile but has transparent pixels. This is important to understand. It is also why the pointer-events have to be handled (turned on and off), because the elements are still there and can still be interacted with. So when they are hidden, we have to disable the pointer-events. And when the element comes back into visibility, we have to enable the pointer-events.

The other thing that you might have to look out for is that the answer uses offsetWidth. For simple navbar contents, this is fine. But in my case I have layers of flexbox and in the end the div that contained the menu was being squished due to flexbox and even though the overflow contents were being hidden, the offsetWidth was being shrunk. I switched to scrollWidth to get the true width of the menu and then it worked greata again.

Comment: Thanks, I was using v-if to switch back and forth between the mobile and desktop toolbar because that seems like the natural thing to do. As a result, I wasn't thinking of having them both in the dom at once. Also, looking at your example, I see I wasn't handling the case where the list of menu items change size.

Comment: As I applied this to my complex navbar, I realized that I had to rethink my approach (everything is still in the dom and takes up screen space due to the visibility property) and I had to switch to scrollWidth instead of the proposed offsetWidth due to layers of flexbox.